# If the folder exist, show the following message

Tags: powershell

I have one question. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, I wrote the following script to tell me if the folder exists to show a message, but it is now showing it.

```
If (Test-Path -path ($LabServer + $CaseName) -PathType Container){
             Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
             [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Folder name exists, please enter a new name')
```

The script is supposed to create multiple folders in a specific location. I want to check if the folder name (Case Name) already exists, and if it does, do not create the folder with the same name, but the script continues and creates the folder and sub-folders.

Here is the full script.
Thank you for all your help

```
# Load required assemblies
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

# Drawing form and controls
$CreateFolder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $CreateFolder.Text = "Create Multiple Custodian Folders"
    $CreateFolder.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,415)
    $CreateFolder.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $CreateFolder.TopMost = $true
    $CreateFolder.MaximizeBox = $false
    $CreateFolder.MinimizeBox = $false
    $CreateFolder.ControlBox = $true
    $CreateFolder.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $CreateFolder.Font = "Segoe UI"


#======================== CASE NAME ========================#
# adding a label to my form
$label_message = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_message.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,8)
    $label_message.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,15)
    $label_message.Text = "Case Name"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($label_message)    
# CaseName    
    $CaseName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $CaseName.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,30)
    $CaseName.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,25)
    $CaseName.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($CaseName)


#======================== DROPBOX ========================#
$label_messageCombobox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_messageCombobox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,60)
    $label_messageCombobox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,15)
    $label_messageCombobox.Text = "Pick a Server"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($label_messageCombobox)    

$DropdownBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $DropdownBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,80)
    $DropdownBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,15)
    $DropdownBox.Height = 200
    $Dropdownbox.DropDownStyle = "DropDownList"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($DropdownBox)
    
    $Servers = @("Lab Machine 40","Lab Machine 45","Lab Machine 50","Lab Machine 55")


    foreach($Server in $Servers){
        $DropdownBox.Items.Add($Server) | Out-Null
    }
#======================== FUNCTION TO GET SERVER ========================#
Function Get-Server(){
    $SelectedServer = $DropdownBox.SelectedItem.ToString()

    if($SelectedServer -eq "Lab Machine 50") {
        $Script:LabServer = Set-Location "\\Server50\K$" -PassThru
    }
    elseif($SelectedServer -eq "Lab Machine 55") {
        $Script:LabServer = Set-Location "\\Server55\K$" -PassThru
    }
    elseif($SelectedServer -eq "Lab Machine 40") {
        $Script:LabServer = Set-Location "\\Server40\K$" -PassThru
    }
    elseif($SelectedServer -eq "Lab Machine 45") {
        $Script:LabServer = Set-Location "\\Server45\K$" -PassThru
    }
}

#======================== INPUTBOX ========================#
$label_message2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_message2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,110)
    $label_message2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,15)
    $label_message2.Text = "Custodian Names"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($label_message2)    
    
# Inputbox    
    $Inputbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $Inputbox.Multiline = $True;
    $Inputbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,130)
    $Inputbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
    $Inputbox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($Inputbox)

 #======================== BUTTON ========================#   
# add a button ti create folder
$button_ClickMe = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_ClickMe.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(45,340)
    $button_ClickMe.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $button_ClickMe.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_ClickMe.Text = "Create Folders"
    $button_ClickMe.Add_Click({
    
    #$FolderExist =  $LabServer.Text + $CaseName.Text

    If ($CaseName.TextLength -eq 0){
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Please Enter a Case Name')
    }
    else {
        If (Test-Path -path ($LabServer + $CaseName) -PathType Container){
            Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Folder name exists, please enter a new name')
        }
        else {
            if ($Inputbox.TextLength -eq 0){
                Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Please enter 1 custodian name')
            }
            else {
                Get-Server
                Set-Location $LabServer
                New-Item $CaseName.Text -type directory 
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
                Set-Location ($LabServer.Text + $CaseName.Text)
                ForEach ($Folder in $Inputbox.lines) {
                    New-Item $Folder -type directory
                }
                 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
                 [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Folders were created')
                 [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit()
                       
            }
        }
    }

 })
     
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($button_ClickMe)

# show form
$CreateFolder.Add_Shown({$CreateFolder.Activate()})
[void] $CreateFolder.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: What's the content of `$LabServer + $CaseName`??  What's `$CaseName`?  ... don't answer ... check it!!   You may output the variables to check if they contain what you expect. ;-)

Comment: Are you *sure* that there's a trailing backslash on `$LabServer`? I'd do `If (Test-Path -path (Join-Path $LabServer  $CaseName) -PathType Container` to make sure the path is formed correctly in your test. Like, if `$LabServer` is `"\\LabServer01\d$\CaseFiles"` and `$CaseName` is `"4771893"` then the path you are testing is `"\\LabServer01\d$\CaseFiles4771893"` which probably won't exist, but you can definitely change to `"\\LabServer01\d$\CaseFiles"` and then create the folder `"4771893"`

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered your own question here:
`#$FolderExist =  $LabServer.Text + $CaseName.Text`

Check out the comments in the code:

```
If ($CaseName.TextLength -eq 0)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Please Enter a Case Name')
}
else
{
    # If we are here $LabServer is not defined because Get-Server did not run yet
        
    # You can take 2 different approaches, either use your function or
    # Test-Path using the ComboBox
    # Approach 1: Define $LabServer
    Get-Server
    
    # Now you can Test-Path
    $path = Join-Path $LabServer -ChildPath $CaseName.Text
    If (Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)
    {
        .....
    }
        
    # Approach 2:
    $path = Join-Path ("\\{0}\K$" -f $DropdownBox.SelectedItem) -ChildPath $CaseName.Text
    If (Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)
    {
        .....
    }
.....
```

#### Edit

I think it's worth adding a few recommendations to reduce the number of nested conditions you have on your `AddClick` listener.

- First, by default at the start of your form, disable the button:

```
$button_ClickMe.Enabled = $false
```

- Now you can add 2 listeners on `TextChanged` for both `TextBox`:

```
$textChangedEvent = {
    if($caseName.TextLength -and $DropdownBox.SelectedItem -and $Inputbox.TextLength)
    {
        $button_ClickMe.Enabled = $true
    }
    else
    {
        $button_ClickMe.Enabled = $false
    }
}

$CaseName.Add_TextChanged($textChangedEvent)
$Inputbox.Add_TextChanged($textChangedEvent)
```

With this you can remove the 2 conditions you have on `$CaseName.TextLength -eq 0` and `$Inputbox.TextLength -eq 0`.

- Lastly, your `AddClick` event would look like this (Note that you wouldn't need the `Get-Server` function):

```
$buttonClickEvent = {
    $path = "\\{0}\K$" -f $DropdownBox.SelectedItem
    $path = Join-Path $path -ChildPath $CaseName.Text

    if(Test-Path $path -PathType Container)
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Folder name exists, please enter a new name')
        return
    }

    New-Item $path -Type Directory
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    
    foreach($folder in $Inputbox.Lines)
    {
        $folder = $Folder.Trim()
        $newFolder = Join-Path $path -ChildPath $folder
        New-Item $newFolder -Type Directory
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Folders were created')
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit()
    }
}

$button_ClickMe.Add_Click($buttonClickEvent)
```